# How to use cache filter?

Tags: python, caching, browser-cache

I'm having problem with cache filter.

The idea is to not cache the responses that contain `"incomplete_result":true`

This is my filter function:

```py
import requests
import requests_cache

def phrase_filter(response: requests.models.Response)->bool:
    if '"incomplete_results":true' in response.text:
        return False
    return True
```

But when I test it out by this code:

```py
requests_cache.install_cache('demo_cache',expired_after=600,filter_fn=phrase_filter)
requests_cache.clear()

url1 = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/KienTrann/requests-cache-testing/main/should_be_cached.txt'
url2 = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/KienTrann/requests-cache-testing/main/should_not_be_cached.txt'

with requests_cache.enabled():
    r = requests.get(url1) # First request
    r = requests.get(url1) # Second request
    print(f'Text from url1:\n{r.text}')
    assert r.from_cache==True
    #
    r1 = requests.get(url2) # First request
    r1 = requests.get(url2) # Second request
    print('---')
    print(f'Text from url2:\n{r1.text}')
    assert r1.from_cache==False

requests_cache.disabled()
```

And here is the result:

```py
Text from url1:
abc
xyz
"incomplete_results":false

---
Text from url2:
abc
xyz
"incomplete_results":true

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ADMIN\source\repos\LearningPython\py_2\py_2.py", line 25, in <module>
    assert r1.from_cache==False
AssertionError
```

I don't understand why `r1` was cached.

What is the problem? And how can I fix it?

Thank you for taking time to answer

Answer (score 2):

## Patching

Looks like you were almost there! `requests_cache.enabled()` and `disabled()` are contextmanager alternatives to `install_cache()` and `uninstall_cache()`. Just pass your settings to `enabled()` instead of `install_cache()`:

```py
with requests_cache.enabled('demo_cache', expire_after=600, filter_fn=phrase_filter):
    # ... make requests
```

This is basically the same as:

```py
requests_cache.install_cache('demo_cache', expire_after=600, filter_fn=phrase_filter)
# ... make requests
requests_cache.uninstall_cache()
```

## Sessions

Personally I'd recommend using `requests_cache.CachedSession` instead of the patching methods, because it makes it more explicit what's being cached, and if you want to make non-cached requests, you can just use the regular `requests` functions. There's more info in the docs here: https://requests-cache.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user_guide/general.html

Example:

```py
from requests import Response
from requests_cache import CachedSession

def phrase_filter(response: Response) -> bool:
    return '"incomplete_results":true' not in response.text

url1 = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/KienTrann/requests-cache-testing/main/should_be_cached.txt'
url2 = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/KienTrann/requests-cache-testing/main/should_not_be_cached.txt'
session = CachedSession('demo_cache', expire_after=600, filter_fn=phrase_filter)
session.cache.clear()

nonfiltered_response = session.get(url1)
nonfiltered_response = session.get(url1)
assert nonfiltered_response.from_cache is True

filtered_response = session.get(url2)
filtered_response = session.get(url2)
assert filtered_response.from_cache is False
```

## Debugging

If you run into similar issues in the future where you're not sure why a response is or isn't getting cached, you can just enable debug logging:

```py
import logging
logging.basicConfig(level='DEBUG')
```

And you'll get caching info for each response like this:

```
DEBUG:requests_cache.session: Pre-cache checks for response from https://raw.githubusercontent.com/KienTrann/requests-cache-testing/main/should_not_be_cached.txt: 
{
    'disabled cache': False,
    'disabled method': False,
    'disabled status': False,
    'disabled by filter': True,
    'disabled by headers or expiration params': False,
}
```

More info in the docs here: https://requests-cache.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user_guide/troubleshooting.html

Answer (score 0):

I also tried this and cannot get it to work:

```
# Added by Eurico Covas
# see https://requests-cache.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user_guide/filtering.html
@staticmethod
def filter_by_error(response: requests.models.Response) -> bool:
    """Don't cache responses with ErrMsg"""
    if response is None:
       return True
    if response.ok ==False:
       return True
    if len(response.json()['GDSSDKResponse']) == 1:
        if len(response.json()['GDSSDKResponse'][0]) >= 1:
           if "ErrMsg" in response.json()['GDSSDKResponse'][0].keys():
              if response.json()['GDSSDKResponse'][0]['ErrMsg'] is not None and response.json()['GDSSDKResponse'][0]['ErrMsg'] != '':
                  return True
    return False

def __init__(self, username, password, verify=True, debug=False, request_caching_enabled=False):
    assert username is not None
    assert password is not None
    assert verify is not None
    assert debug is not None
    assert request_caching_enabled is not None
    self._username = username
    self._password = password
    self._verify = verify
    self._debug = debug
    self._request_caching_enabled=request_caching_enabled
    if self._request_caching_enabled:
        self.request_count = self.get_cached_request_count()
    if not self._verify:
        requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings(InsecureRequestWarning)
    if self._debug:
        self.enable_request_debugging()
    else:
        self.enable_error_logging()
    # cache requests for 30*24 hours = 1 month!
    if self._request_caching_enabled:
        requests_cache.install_cache('capiq_cache', backend='sqlite', expire_after=30*86400, allowable_methods=('POST',), filter_fn=self.filter_by_error)
```

but

```
    response = requests.post(self._endpoint, headers=self._headers, data=json.dumps(req),
                             auth=HTTPBasicAuth(self._username, self._password), verify=self._verify)
```

does not call filter_by_error() ever...

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30895735)